# Efficient index to locate unprocessed entries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a MySQL table that contains millions of entries.

Each entry must be processed at some point by a cron job.

I need to be able to quickly locate unprocessed entries, using an index.

So far, I have used the following approach: I add a nullable, indexed `processedOn` column that contains the timestamp at which the entry has been processed:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    ...
    processedOn INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL,
    KEY (processedOn)
);
```

And then retrieve an unprocessed entry using:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE processedOn IS NULL LIMIT 1;
```

Thanks to MySQL's [IS NULL optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/is-null-optimization.html), the query is very fast, as long as the number of unprocessed entries if small (which is almost always the case).

This approach is good enough: it does the job, but at the same time I feel like the index is wasted because it's only ever used for `WHERE processedOn IS NULL` queries, and never for locating a precise value or range of values for this field. So this has an inevitable impact on storage space and `INSERT` performance, as every single timestamp is indexed for nothing.

Is there a better approach? Ideally the index would just contain pointers to the unprocessed rows, and no pointer to any processed row.

I know I could split this table into 2 tables, but I'd like to keep it in a single table.

Comment: What you want can't be achieved with a single table. You want a junction table which contains only unprocessed rows. This is easily maintained with  a trigger (`insert into unprocessed...`). What you're left with is an inner join  and that gives you unprocessed jobs, using primary key of your table. That's the best indexing strategy since you'll be using the primary key for lookup. Creating a view which you can query as a regular table will make this process even easier since you're left with `SELECT * FROM unprocessed_view` or something similar.

Comment: One other thing - you're working merely with millions of rows. That's not that much, and in your case - I wouldn't bother optimizing this at all - simply remove the index. Let MySQL do a full table scan and simply allocate sufficient resources so I/O is fast enough, that index you're using is practically useless. Certain things can't be improved by smart coding, at some point you will exceed good programming practices and be left at mercy of your hardware. The other approach is what I listed before - a junction table containing IDs of unprocessed entries.

Comment: And what percentage of the entire table plus current indexes would this extra index be?  Under 10%, so not worth worrying about.  (But I enjoyed giving you a long answer.)

Comment: @Mjh The junction table with the trigger is a very interesting idea, thanks for sharing it!

Comment: @Mjh About the millions of rows, as an example, I have a table with 30 million rows, 9GB data + 2GB indexes. On my pretty high-end server (Xeon E5, 4 cores 8 threads, 3.7 GHz, 64GB RAM, 3x 160GB SSD disks in RAID-1), it takes at least 5 seconds for a full table scan. This is a pretty big table, and it could certainly be smaller for a simple queue. But if such a full table scan is reasonable for one-off queries, it is still IMHO unacceptable for cron jobs repeatedly finding a row to process. In this case, my original index works much better even if it's only used for `WHERE ... IS NULL`.

Comment: May I suggest looking into Percona's TokuDB storage engine? It's an efficient ACID compliant engine that's on par with InnoDB or faster, but it's much more efficient at data storage. The data set you described could be saved using at least 20% less space, and it's quite possible you can experience even less space used.

Comment: @Mjh This is interesting, but I'd like to stay with MySQL 5.7 and InnoDB for now.

Comment: I'm mentioning it so you're aware of it :) also, the mentioned engine is a drop-in replacement for InnoDB. At my company, we've been using it for quite a while now. However, at 64 gigs of ram, you shouldn't have any issues with full table scans. Is your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` set to appropriate size for the data set to fit in RAM? Full table scan, even if the data isn't in RAM, really shouldn't take that long, especially on an SSD (I get better performance on a larger table using an SSD). Is that a virtual SSD or physical?

Comment: @Mjh I have set `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32G`, and it is a physical SSD. 8GB is still quite a lot of data to go through, though. Maybe the fragmentation has an effect on the speed, as well?

Comment: @Benjamin - something isn't right, I've a test machine with 50 GB of data and a full table scan is lower than 2 seconds, it's similar to yours, plus I have way less powerful CPU. I'm running only 1 SSD and my buffer pool is only 1GB (so I can play with disk seek instead of loading everything from RAM). Fragmentation shouldn't have such an impact on retrieval.

Comment: I don't know, but TBH even 2 seconds is too much. I need a milliseconds solution, as this query will be repeated very often!

Answer (score 1):

What comes to my mind is to create a isProcessed column, with default value = 'N' and you set to 'Y' when processed (at the same time you set the processedOn column). Then create an index on the isProcessed field. When you query (with the where clause WHERE isProcessed = 'N'), it will respond very fast.

**UPDATE: ALTERNATIVE with partitioning:**

Create your table with partitions and define a field that will have just 2 values 1 or 0. This will create one partition for records with the field = 1 and another for records with field = 0.

```
create table test (field1 int, field2 int DEFAULT 0)
PARTITION BY LIST(field2) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES IN (0),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (1)  
);
```

This way, if you want to query only the records with the field equal to one of the values, just do this:

```
select * from test partition (p0);
```

The query above will show only records with field2 = 0.
And if you need to query all records together, you just query the table normally:

```
select * from test;
```

As far as I was able to understand, this will help you with your need.

Comment: The problem is the same, the index will contain a pointer to every row with `isProcessed` = 'Y', with the same wasted resources issue!

Comment: @Benjamin, I think there is no standard way of doing what you want, and to be honest, you may be concerned with resources that any database is more than able to manage. This is how database indexes works.

Comment: I was thinking of something like a selective index, that would only contain pointers for values that I choose; but I'm not sure whether this is something MySQL, or any other RDBMS for that matter, supports.

Comment: Yes, I don't know of any RDBMS with selective index. But, for creating smaller indexes to save resources, go for the index on a smaller field, like the one I suggested.

Comment: @Walter, FYI - MS SQL has "filtered indexes" which are perfect for this sort of application.

Comment: @Gavin Lock, interesting, I really do not have used this type of indexing in MSSQL.

Comment: MySQL won't even use such an index. A binary column or a column with deteriorating rate of uniqueness is a poor index candidate. As the records grow, the cardinality goes down. Indexing such a column won't help whatsoever, so this answer is misleading and inaccurate.

Comment: @Mjh, thanks for your comment. The idea behind the index that the OP wants is to locate easily all the records with a specific condition. He was interested in filtered index, to be more to the point, but this does not work on MySQL.

Comment: This kind of index won't work anywhere, there's no system in existence that can use such an index and retrieve records faster than doing a full table scan, it's basically pointless. My comment isn't an "attack" on your answer, it's simply how data structures work. Technically, such an index can make things worse since MySQL will have to read the index first and then still scan the whole table. It's better if it scans the whole table. Also, millions of entries is still low amount of data for properly configured MySQL, and OP said he's only working with millions, not billions.

Comment: @Njh, I did not have considered an attack.

Comment: I like the partition idea, I did not think of it. Do you think there is a need for explicitly specifying the partition name when doing the query? Can't MySQL optimize the query by itself when the `WHERE` matches the partition?

Comment: That would also happen. But I have showed that so you can see that explicitly.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this approach only saves some disk space in the case that the table does not have any unique indexes (or unique indexes which contains the partitioning column as part of their definitions). Otherwise, if it has a unique index which does not contain the partition column, MySQL will complain, and you won't be able to create the partitions.

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple answers and comments on others' answers.

First, let me assume that the `PRIMARY KEY` for `Foo` is `id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT` (4 bytes) and that the table is Engine=InnoDB.

**Indexed Extra column**

The index for the extra column would be, per row, the width of the extra column and the `PRIMARY KEY`, plus a bunch of overhead.  With your `processedOn`, you are talking about 8 bytes (2 INTs).  With a simple flag, 5 bytes.

**Separate table**

This table would have only `id` for the *unprocessed* items.  It would take extra code to populate it.  It's size would stay at some "high-water mark".  So, if there were a burst of unprocessed items, it would grow, but not shrink back.  (Here's a *rare* case where `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is useful.)  InnoDB requires a `PRIMARY KEY`, and `id` would work perfectly.  So, one column, no extra index.  It is a lot smaller than the extra index discussed above.  Finding something to work on:

```
$id = SELECT id FROM tbl LIMIT 1;   -- don't care which one
process it
DELETE FROM tbl where id = $id
```

**2 PARTITIONs, one processed, one not**

No.  When you change a row from processed to unprocessed, the row must be removed from one partition and inserted into the other.  This is done behind the scenes by your `UPDATE ... SET flag = 1`.  Also, both partitions have the "high-water" issue -- they will grow but not shrink.  And the space overhead for partitioning *may* be as much as the other solutions.

`SELECT by PARTITION ...` requires 5.6.  Without that, you would need an `INDEX`, so you are back to the index issues.

**Continual Scanning**

This incurs zero extra disk space.  (That's better than you had hoped for, correct?)  And it is not too inefficient.  Here's how it works.  Here is some pseudo-code to put into your cron job.  But don't make it a cron job.  Instead, let it run all the time.  (The reason will become clear, I hope.)

```
SELECT @a := 0;
Loop:
    # Get a clump
    SELECT @z := id FROM Foo WHERE id > @a ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000,1;
    if no results, Set @z to MAX(id)
    # Find something to work on in that clump:
    SELECT @id := id FROM Foo
        WHERE id > @a
          AND id <= @z
          AND not-processed
        LIMIT 1;
    if you found something, process it and set @z := @id
    SET @a := @z;
    if @a >= MAX(id), set @a := 0;   # to start over
    SLEEP 2 seconds   # or some amount that is a compromise
Go Loop
```

Notes:

- It walks through the table with minimal impact.
- It works even with gaps in `id`.  (It could be made simpler if there were no gaps.)  (If the PK is not `AUTO_INCREMENT`, it is almost identical.)
- The `sleep` is to be a 'nice guy'.

**Selective Index**

MariaDB's dynamic columns and MySQL 5.7's JSON can index things, and I *think* they are "selective".  One state would be to have the column empty, the other would be to have the flag set in the dynamic/json column.  This will take some research to verify, and may require an upgrade.